# What could be the reason that my "Displayport To HDMI Adapter" does not work?

Tags: hdmi, video-conversion, cable, displayport, display-adapter

Recently, I bought this: https://www.dustinhome.se/product/5010763579/displayport-to-hdmi-adapter

It was not cheap and it feels quite heavy and quality-ish in my hand. I'm not at all convinced that the error is simply that there is something wrong with it. It seems like too simple of a device to really "break" in that sense.

My tests:

1. I plug a HDMI cable into my Raspberry Pi and into the HDMI connector on a TV. The RPI's picture is shown. Thus, I make the conclusion that there is nothing wrong with the RPI nor the HDMI cable.
2. I plug the very same HDMI cable into the very same Raspberry Pi and, since my computer monitor does not have a HDMI socket, but only DisplayPort, I plug the other end of the HDMI cable into my "Displayport To HDMI Adapter", which I then plug into the DisplayPort connector on the monitor. There is no picture signal whatsoever. The simple conclusion would be that the adapter is faulty, but I'm not convinced.

I have repeated these steps many times, to rule out any "loose cables", etc. I have also specifically set the video mode on the monitor to "DisplayPort", rather than "auto", just to make 100% clear to the monitor that it's supposed to be displaying the HDMI-turned-DisplayPort signal and nothing else. (Besides, nothing else is connected to the monitor anyway.)

Another reason I don't think the adapter is physically/electronically "fried" is that I've in the past had similar issues when I tried to use various adapters for video signals. It seems like a common problem, but it makes no sense to me. What exactly is the problem? As far as the monitor is concerned, I have plugged in a DisplayPort video output device -- not a HDMI one. After all, that is the whole point of the adapter!

I also should point out that I have turned the RPI off/on again several times, with the HDMI cable already plugged in.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Yeah; What you purchased was a DisplayPort to HDMI adapter this means it’s single direction, meaning, a DisplayPort source to a HDMI monitor.  Since your source is incompatible with DisplayPort that’s the reason it’s not working.  What you have purchased is incompatible with your setup.  You should return it

Comment: @Ramhound That's... well, see my other comment. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adapter is for converting a DisplayPort source port to an HDMI sink port (likely it is even a passive one that works only on a dual-mode DP (a.k.a. DP++) port).

In your case you'll need to find something called "(convert from) HDMI (signal) to DisplayPort (signal) active cable". You probably won't find an adapter in similar style (DP plug/male and HDMI female/port without a cable) that works as you desired / expected (i.e. can be plugged into a DP sink that converts incoming HDMI signal).

Comment: Really? They are not two-way? Why on Earth would they make such a thing? I thought I only had to keep track of male/female connectors, but it's internally different on top of that? Wow... Why would they do it like that?

Comment: Yeah because unlike HDMI and DVI, DP use a different method/protocol for transmission (TMDS vs micro packets). Btw AFAICT it's sort of a convention that vendors do not produce non-cable active adapter that should be plugged on a sink. (It could be that I've not seen enough though.)

Comment: @JB - Because of a limitation of the adapter, in order to be bidirectional, it would cost twice as much.  The specifications of the the product were clear this was the case (it was Omni-directional)

Comment: Display port adapters are pretty much universally uni-directional.  It is the way displayport is designed.